# Getting Specific Ethernet Statistics

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Is there any way to get `rx_broadcast` value from `/sys/class/net/<intf>/..`?

I am using the following commands `ETHTOOL_GSTATS` and `SIOCETHTOOL` for `IOCTL` to get the ethernet statistics, but I am interested in some script which reads the values from `/sys/class/net`

I looked into `/sys/class/net/...`, but could not find any entry.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to get rx_broadcast value from /sys/class/net//..?

No, as it says at
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/statistics.html:

> Each device directory in sysfs contains a statistics directory
> (e.g. /sys/class/net/lo/statistics/) with files corresponding to
> members of struct rtnl_link_stats64.

and `rtnl_link_stats64` doesn't have a field representing
`rx_broadcast`.

Notice that there is a ready to use tool called `ethtool` maintained
at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git that you
can use in your script:

```
$ ethtool -S eth0 | grep rx_broadcast
     rx_broadcast: 48728
```

If you don't want to add new programs to your system or write C
programs that use `ioctl()` you have to use another scripting language
that is available on your system and has ioctl support built-in, for
example [ethtool -S in
Python](https://gist.github.com/yunazuno/d7cd7e1e127a39192834c75d85d45df9).

Comment: In the above command is that value in bytes or packets?

Comment: I think it depends on the driver, e1000e for example reports it in packets.